# SSRS Report Formatting Problems in ASP Report Application

Tags: asp.net, ssrs-2008, report-viewer2010

I have an SSRS report that is being displayed in a custom asp.net report application through the ReportViewer control (VS2010).  The SSRS report renders fine on the Report Server and through Report Manager, but in the Report Application, the column widths and heights are stretched and expanded, throwing the formatting of the tablix completely off.  I believe it's an issue with the tags in the ReportViewer control.  Does anyone have any idea at the top of their head as to why this may be occurring?  Thank you kindly in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Is your ReportViewer control on an ordinary ASPX page on an unsecured site or is it on a CMS page (SharePoint, DNN, Plumtree) or behind some authentication layer or maybe some proxy? The problem is that the CSS for the report is getting lost.

Comment: Thanks tgolisch, but I'm not sure it's an issue with the CSS. The color of the parameter banner is modified in the .net Application, which I don't think would be possible if it wasn't pulling the CSS settings from the one specified under the <HTMLViewerStyleSheet> of the .config file.  Is a different CSS style referred to for the report body that could be affecting the column widths?  Then again, the report loads fine in Mozilla, but not IE. So I doubt it's a CSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might help or not but its better to give it a try.

If you right click on the properties of the Data-set and go to Options tab in there you would find Width sensitivity which is default to auto. Please make it to false and try it.

Comment: Thank you Akarsh, I tried this solution but it didn't do it. I also tried modifying all the stretched column cells CanGrow property to False, and no luck. Since it loads properly in Report Manager, I don't think it's an issue with the RDL/report object, but more likely it is the .net application.  Then again, it loads fine in Mozilla but not in IE9, so I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of thoughts on SSRS hosted through a different front end:

1. ASP.NET or whatever is probably using a form of CSS implemented through 'master pages' if you are doing the standard ASP.NET creation through VS.  Can you turn it off temporarily to troubleshoot or create a page that does not implement the master page and then host the SSRS through that?
2. Is this all reports from SSRS or just some of them?  The SSRS language is just XML and you may be able to nest a report object in say a rectangle and see if that can trick the front end's markup.
3. Is this being hosted through the 'ReportViewer' object with a direct link to the SSRS Web Service?  You also may call the web service through many other means, however they take more time to set up.  You can view an SSRS call to the service through an html 'form' or also you can set up your own proxy classes in C# to get the binary form of a render of a type like Excel, PDF, MHTML, etc.